# Freeze first column and detail

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table that I need to be able to stick the first column and a detail associated with it.  The cell needs to be able to grow vertically to display hidden list and a child div is positioned absolutely next to it.  To achieve that effect I relatively positioned the table cell.  The behavior can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmo28zz4/1/

```
.headcol {
    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
}
```

By doing so, I can't absolutely position the cell as seen in other examples.  If there's another way to achieve the desired effect of my expander/details, I'd be open to that as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles:

```
.content tr::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.content td:first-child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Change `updateDetailWidths()` as follows:

```
function updateDetailWidths() {
  var mw= 0;
  $('.content td:first-child')
    .each(function() {
      mw= Math.max(mw, $(this).width());
      $(this).parent().height($(this).height());
    })
    .width(mw);
  $('<style>.content tr::before{width:'+mw+'px}</style>').appendTo('head');
  $('.headcol-detail').width($('.content').innerWidth()-mw);
}
```

Add the following code at the end of the click handler:

```
$('td > div:first-child').click(function () {
  ...
  var tr= $(this).closest('tr');
  tr.height($('td:first', tr).height());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmo28zz4/3/)

This does the following:

1. Makes the absolute-positioned first `td`s the same width.
2. Sets each row to be the height of its first `td`.
3. Adds a pseudo-element to each `tr`, which pushes the second and subsequent `td`s to the right of the absolute-positioned first `td`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  One minor change, added: $(this).closest('tr').css('height', $(this).parent().height());
to the click/toggle function.

Comment: Makes sense.  Interesting question and challenge.